# Grunt Globbing patterns

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

What is the pattern needed to achieve the following.

1. Match all the html file in the directory `.tmp`
2. Match all the html file in .tmp/views and all subdirectories of it (recursively to any depth)

This is to register `livereload` task in Grunt file.

I tried few varieties of below config. It matches all files in `.tmp`, but not recursively in `.tmp/views`

Also tried,

```
 '.tmp/{,views/**/}*.html'
```

but the same result.

> ```
>  livereload: {
>                     options: {
>                         livereload: LIVERELOAD_PORT
>                     },
>                     files: [
>                         '.tmp/{,views/**}*.html'
>                     ]
>                 }
> ```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to get the matching you need by passing two elements in the files array:

```
files: [
    '.tmp/*.html',
    '.tmp/views/**/*.html',
]
```

This will match any `.html` files directly below `.tmp/`, as well as any `.html` file in `.tmp/views/`, whether directly under that directory or deeper (the `/**/` part).

Comment: +1, it works. For completeness, how it differ from the pattern  '.tmp/{,views/**/}*.html' thanks.

Comment: I have a feeling it's because the expression before the comma is empty, although I'm not sure. Either way, I'd use the array syntax above as it's much more clear as to what it's matching